# Next js on Hostinger VPS does not connect to correct Express js backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, vps

I am running two instances on the VPS. One serving the frontend, other the backend. The front is a React application with Next js. The back is an Express js server. The front fetches some data from the back in the following code:

```
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.status === 'success') {
                    toast('You are Logged in')
                    localStorage.setItem('LinkTreeToken', data.token)
                    router.push('/dashboard')
                }
                if (data.status === 'not found') {
                    toast.error('Invalid email or password')
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

However, it connects to my local machine express js server instead of the VPS one. When the server on my machine is disabled, no data is fetched. I am sure that the server on the VPS is working since I can access it from my machine.

I am using Hostinger with CloudPanel. I have set up the website using Cloud Panel as a node js application on port 3000. The front is served successfully, the only issue is with communication channel.

Comment: Don't you think that you need to change `http://localhost:8080` with your `VPS`'s `IP` or `Domain`?

Comment: I tried that already, it didn't work. I got something along the lines of "Mixed http requests", because the website is https but the vps is http. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Share some snippets in a repo to check the issue and some errors as well. It maybe due to missing route in backend with /api